# Error 500 when adding links to errors 425 up to 499 on htdocs

Tags: apache

I have an `.htdocs` file where it has several error redirects (to all kinds of HTTP error, and it's the only thing on file): `ErrorDocument 400 /PROJETOS/error.php?status=error_400` however when I add respective lines to errors `HTTP 425` up to `HTTP 499` gives the `HTTP server internal error 500`. Does anyone know why?

**Apache version:** 2.4.10

Error Screen:

[image]

If I remove this line (425 up to 499): `ErrorDocument 499 /PROJETOS/error.php?status=error_499` works fine.

Comment: can u pass the error log from apache here?

Comment: Look in the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These codes are **invalid** or not **implemented** yet as you can see on the site [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)(Internet Assigned Numbers Authority):

```
425 Unassigned  
426 Upgrade Required    [RFC7231, Section 6.5.15]
427 Unassigned
430 Unassigned
432-499 Unassigned
```